# Converting format of polygon variable

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I'm trying to generate some generic 3d box type shapes out of planes in MATLAB. My knowledge of linear algebra is limited, so I've been following this http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/3d-polygon.html simple method to generate the planes making up the shape by specifying 4 points of the plane and using fill3.

However, I later need to use  geom3d functions to calculate the distance to each plane from a point inside the space. Geom3d functions require the plane to be in the format as quoted below, which a handle variable to fill3 is not.

```
%   The created plane data has the following format:
%   PLANE = [X0 Y0 Z0  DX1 DY1 DZ1  DX2 DY2 DZ2], with
%   - (X0, Y0, Z0) is a point belonging to the plane
%   - (DX1, DY1, DZ1) is a first direction vector
%   - (DX2, DY2, DZ2) is a second direction vector
%   The 2 direction vectors are normalized and orthogonal.
%   The created plane data has the following format:
%   PLANE = [X0 Y0 Z0  DX1 DY1 DZ1  DX2 DY2 DZ2], with
%   - (X0, Y0, Z0) is a point belonging to the plane
%   - (DX1, DY1, DZ1) is a first direction vector
%   - (DX2, DY2, DZ2) is a second direction vector
%   The 2 direction vectors are normalized and orthogonal.
```

Does anyone know how I might generate or convert a variable of a plane from fill3 into that format?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: As @Wolfie has already said, though familiar with geometry and matlab, I am unable to understand what you are speaking about and what are your objectives. Draw examples and show them...

Comment: @Wolfie Amended

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker Amended